# How to change the auto numbering id field to serial type in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, autonumber

I have a Database which is migrated from `MSSQL` to `PostgreSQL(9.2)`.

This Database have 100+ tables, These table have autonumbering filed(PRIMARY KEY field), given below is an example for a table

```
CREATE TABLE company
(
  companyid integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('seq_company_id'::regclass),
  company character varying(100),
  add1 character varying(100),
  add2 character varying(100),
  add3 character varying(100),
  phoneoff character varying(30),
  phoneres character varying(30)
  CONSTRAINT gcompany_pkey PRIMARY KEY (companyid)
)
```

sample data

```
 INSERT INTO company (company, add1, add2, add3, phoneoff, phoneres) VALUES   
 ('company1','add1','add2','add3','00055544','7788848');
 INSERT INTO company (company, add1, add2, add3, phoneoff, phoneres) VALUES  
 ('company2','add9','add5','add2','00088844','7458844');
 INSERT INTO company (company, add1, add2, add3, phoneoff, phoneres) VALUES 
 ('company5','add5','add8','add7','00099944','2218844');
```

and below is the `sequence` for this table

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_company_id
 INCREMENT 1
 MINVALUE 1
 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
 START 1
 CACHE 1;
ALTER TABLE seq_company_id
OWNER TO postgres;
```

while reading PostgreSQL Documentation i read about [`Serial Types`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) so i wish to change all the existing auto numbering fields to serial.
How to do it?

---

i have tried

```
alter table company alter column companyid type serial
```

---

```
 ERROR:  type "serial" does not exist
     ********** Error **********
```

Comment: i have read _http://stackoverflow.com/a/16474765/3814846_ answer but in my case i already have _sequence_ !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed no data type `serial`. It is just a shorthand notation for a default value populated from sequence (see [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) for details), essentially what you have now.

The only difference between your setup and a column defined as `serial` is that there is a link between the sequence and the column, which you can define manually as well:

```
alter sequence seq_gcompany_id owned by company.companyid;
```

With that link in place you can no longer distinguish your column from a column initially defined as `serial`. What this change does, is that the sequence will automatically be dropped if the table (or the column) is dropped that uses it.

Comment: ok one problem while run  it getting `ERROR:  sequence must have same owner as table it is linked to`

Comment: @keet: well that's pretty clear isn't it? You apparently created the sequence with a different owner than the table. Probably a case of running scripts with the wrong user.