# how to get sequence alter query for all tables in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

As following up my previous [question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25073238/how-to-change-the-auto-numbering-id-field-to-serial-type-in-postgresql) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25073610/3814846).

i need write script to alter sequences for all my tables(100+)
given below is an example for table `gcompany`

```
alter sequence seq_gcompany_id owned by company.companyid;
```

how to get this `Alter` query for all the `sequence` ?

***hint***: all the sequences name starts with  `seq_g`

Comment: good to provide the hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
Select  'alter sequence '||_seq||' owned by '||_table||'.'||_column||';' FROM (SELECT   
  n.nspname AS _schema,
  c.relname AS _table,
  a.attname AS _column,
  SUBSTRING(d.adsrc FROM E'nextval\\(''([^'')]+)''') AS _seq
FROM pg_attrdef       AS d
  JOIN pg_attribute AS a ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
  JOIN pg_class     AS c ON c.oid = d.adrelid
  JOIN pg_namespace AS n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE adsrc LIKE 'nextval(''%') t;
```

and execute the output as `pgScript`

*Read* *about* [*pg_class*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/catalog-pg-class.html) *and* [*pg_attribute*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/catalog-pg-attribute.html)