# postgresql - How can I change the id type of all tables of one existent database

Tags: sql, postgresql, primary-key

I migrated a old mysql database to postgresql.
After finshed all the process, and inserting the data I found out that the way that I've created the Pkey is not the correct.
I used integer not Null instead of Serial.

How can I change all the pkeys from my tables to the Serial type without changing all the database?

Thanks !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alter data type of a column to serial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16474720/alter-data-type-of-a-column-to-serial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- No guarantee (I dug this up and altered it a bit)
- might need some additional editing
- **MAKE SURE YOU HAVE A BACKUP**
- [and/or first test on a dummy database]
- for safety, this is run in a 'tmp' schema, to do no unintentional harm.
- this is a few years old, today I would use `format()` to construct the dynamic SQL
- note: this is the old-fashioned way. Maybe nowadays you could just use `alter table tab alter column col type = typ;

---

```
DROP SCHEMA tmp CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA tmp ;
SET search_path=tmp;

        -- Create sequence for column and attacht it as a default
        -- sch := schemaname
        -- tab := tablename
        -- zname := columnname
        -- NOTE:
        -- if 'sch' is NULL, 'public' is used
        -- if 'tab' is NULL, *ALL* tables in the schema are affected.
        -- 'zname' must always be supplied
        -- -----------------------------------------------------------
CREATE FUNCTION inttoseq(sch text, tab text, zname text) RETURNS integer
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$
DECLARE
        zresult text;
        tabname text;
        colname text;
        seqname text;
        schtabname text;
        schseqname text;
        tabcolname text;
        schtabcolname text;
        zrec RECORD;
        zcount INTEGER;
BEGIN
        zcount = 0;
        FOR zrec IN
                SELECT ns.nspname AS sname
                , cl.relname AS tname
                , cl.relowner AS onumm
                , at.attname AS cname
                FROM pg_class cl
                JOIN pg_namespace ns ON ns.oid = cl.relnamespace
                JOIN pg_attribute at ON at.attrelid = cl.oid
                WHERE ns.nspname = COALESCE( sch, 'public' )
                AND (cl.relname = tab OR tab IS NULL)
                AND (at.attname = zname)
        LOOP
                tabname := quote_ident(zrec.tname)
                        ;
                schtabname := quote_ident(zrec.sname) || '.' || tabname
                        ;
                colname := quote_ident(zrec.cname)
                        ;
                tabcolname := tabname || '.' || colname
                        ;
                schtabcolname := schtabname || '.' || colname
                        ;
                seqname := trim(zrec.tname) || '_' || trim(zrec.cname) || '_seq'
                        ;
                schseqname := quote_ident(zrec.sname) || '.' || seqname
                        ;
                zresult := 'CREATE SEQUENCE ' || schseqname
                        || ' MINVALUE 1'
                        || ';'
                        || E'\n'
                        || 'ALTER SEQUENCE ' || schseqname
                        || ' OWNER TO ' || pg_get_userbyid(zrec.onumm)
                        || ';'
                        || E'\n'
                        || 'ALTER TABLE ' || schtabname
                        || ' ALTER COLUMN ' || colname
                        || ' SET DEFAULT nextval(' || quote_literal(schseqname) || ');'
                        || E'\n'
                        || 'ALTER SEQUENCE ' || schseqname
                        || ' OWNED BY ' || schtabcolname  || ';'
                        || E'\n'
                        ;
                -- RAISE NOTICE 'Result:=%', zresult;
                IF (zresult IS NOT NULL) THEN
                        EXECUTE zresult;
                        zcount := zcount +1;
                END IF;
        END LOOP;
                RETURN zcount;
END;
$$;

ALTER FUNCTION inttoseq(sch text, tab text, zname text) OWNER TO postgres;

        -- Set the value for a sequence to the max(value)
        -- in the corresponding column.
CREATE FUNCTION syncseq(sch text, tab text, zname text) RETURNS integer
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$

DECLARE
        zresult text;
        tabname text;
        colname text;
        seqname text;
        schtabname text;
        schseqname text;
        tabcolname text;
        schtabcolname text;
        zrec RECORD;
        zcount INTEGER;
BEGIN
        zcount = 0;
        FOR zrec IN
                SELECT ns.nspname AS sname
                , cl.relname AS tname
                , cl.relowner AS onumm
                , at.attname AS cname
                FROM pg_class cl
                JOIN pg_namespace ns ON ns.oid = cl.relnamespace
                JOIN pg_attribute at ON at.attrelid = cl.oid
                WHERE ns.nspname = COALESCE( sch, 'public' )
                AND (cl.relname = tab OR tab IS NULL)
                AND (at.attname = zname)
        LOOP
                tabname := quote_ident(zrec.tname)
                        ;
                schtabname := quote_ident(zrec.sname) || '.' || tabname
                        ;
                colname := quote_ident(zrec.cname)
                        ;
                tabcolname := tabname || '.' || colname
                        ;
                schtabcolname := schtabname || '.' || colname
                        ;
                seqname := trim(zrec.tname) || '_' || trim(zrec.cname) || '_seq'
                        ;
                schseqname := quote_ident(zrec.sname) || '.' || seqname
                        ;
                zresult := 'ALTER SEQUENCE ' || schseqname
                        || ' MINVALUE 1'
                        || ';'
                        || E'\n'
                        || ' SELECT setval( '
                        || quote_literal(schseqname)
                        || ', COALESCE(GREATEST( zt.' || colname || ' ,1), 1)'
                        || ', True)'
                        || ' FROM ' || schtabname || ' zt;'
                        || E'\n'
                        ;
                -- RAISE NOTICE 'Result:=%', zresult;
                IF (zresult IS NOT NULL) THEN
                        EXECUTE zresult;
                        zcount := zcount +1;
                END IF;
        END LOOP;
                RETURN zcount;
END;
$$;


ALTER FUNCTION syncseq(sch text, tab text, zname text) OWNER TO postgres;


        -- do some testing
CREATE TABLE app_user (
    id bigint NOT NULL
    , username character varying NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO app_user(id, username) VALUES
 ( 1, 'Joan' )
,( 2, 'John' )
,( 3, 'Bill' )
,( 9, 'Hillary' )
        ;
   -- invoke the functions to alter the PK type to SERIAL
SELECT inttoseq( 'tmp', 'app_user', 'id' );
   -- and set the serial to the max value in the column
SELECT syncseq( 'tmp', 'app_user', 'id' );

   -- show it to the world   
\d app_user

SELECT * FROM app_user;
SELECT nextval('app_user_id_seq');

\ds app_user_id_seq
```

The names could be found by consulting the catalogs, looking for the PK, but that is difficult, and possibly dangerous. With the given functions, you'll have to supply the {schemaname,tablename,columnname} (but you can omit schema and table, which is intended to be handy if all your PKs are named 'id' ;-)

Comment: Thanks for you help. I'm tring understand your code, I'll dump the database to performe the tests.
I'm a postgresql n00b, so It is not trivial for me.

Comment: I had another answrer, but the user deleted. So, I don't have another option to compare

Comment: The other answer basically does the same, but manually. (create sequence + attach it to the PK column as a DEFAULT+ set the max value for the sequence to the MAX(PK) ) You could extract the same logic from my answer, if you prefer to do it manually.